# How to search for a certain node based on the name?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I got a force directed graph in D3.js based on this simple example:
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/950642

Now, i added in the CSS part a field to type in some text. My goal is to build a kind of a search box to find nodes based on their names. That means, if i type in "Joly", then the node with that name should be highlighted.
The question is how to solve this problem?

```
  <style> 
    input[type=text] {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 12px 20px;
        margin: 8px 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 2px solid red;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <p>Text fields with borders:</p>

    <form>
      <label for="fname">Some Input</label>
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
    </form>
    <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 500

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .gravity(0.05)
    .distance(100)
    .charge(-100)
    .size([width, height]);

d3.json("graph.json", function(error, json) {
  if (error) throw error;

  force
      .nodes(json.nodes)
      .links(json.links)
      .start();

  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(json.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link");

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(json.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .call(force.drag);

  node.append("image")
      .attr("xlink:href", "https://github.com/favicon.ico")
      .attr("x", -8)
      .attr("y", -8)
      .attr("width", 16)
      .attr("height", 16);

  node.append("text")
      .attr("dx", 12)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name });

  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
  });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search through all the nodes and check the name data value for each node.

```
d3.select("#fname").on("input", function() {
var inputValue = this.value;
node.each(function (d) {
    var highLight = "black";
    if(d.name.toLowerCase() == inputValue.toLowerCase()) highLight = "red";
    d3.select(this).style("fill", highLight);
});
});
```

```js
var width = 960,
    height = 500

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .gravity(0.05)
    .distance(100)
    .charge(-100)
    .size([width, height]);

var json = {"nodes":[{"name":"Myriel","group":1},{"name":"Napoleon","group":1},{"name":"Mlle.Baptistine","group":1},{"name":"Mme.Magloire","group":1},{"name":"CountessdeLo","group":1},{"name":"Geborand","group":1},{"name":"Champtercier","group":1},{"name":"Cravatte","group":1},{"name":"Count","group":1},{"name":"OldMan","group":1},{"name":"Labarre","group":2},{"name":"Valjean","group":2},{"name":"Marguerite","group":3},{"name":"Mme.deR","group":2},{"name":"Isabeau","group":2},{"name":"Gervais","group":2},{"name":"Tholomyes","group":3},{"name":"Listolier","group":3},{"name":"Fameuil","group":3},{"name":"Blacheville","group":3},{"name":"Favourite","group":3},{"name":"Dahlia","group":3},{"name":"Zephine","group":3},{"name":"Fantine","group":3},{"name":"Mme.Thenardier","group":4},{"name":"Thenardier","group":4},{"name":"Cosette","group":5},{"name":"Javert","group":4},{"name":"Fauchelevent","group":0},{"name":"Bamatabois","group":2},{"name":"Perpetue","group":3},{"name":"Simplice","group":2},{"name":"Scaufflaire","group":2},{"name":"Woman1","group":2},{"name":"Judge","group":2},{"name":"Champmathieu","group":2},{"name":"Brevet","group":2},{"name":"Chenildieu","group":2},{"name":"Cochepaille","group":2},{"name":"Pontmercy","group":4},{"name":"Boulatruelle","group":6},{"name":"Eponine","group":4},{"name":"Anzelma","group":4},{"name":"Woman2","group":5},{"name":"MotherInnocent","group":0},{"name":"Gribier","group":0},{"name":"Jondrette","group":7},{"name":"Mme.Burgon","group":7},{"name":"Gavroche","group":8},{"name":"Gillenormand","group":5},{"name":"Magnon","group":5},{"name":"Mlle.Gillenormand","group":5},{"name":"Mme.Pontmercy","group":5},{"name":"Mlle.Vaubois","group":5},{"name":"Lt.Gillenormand","group":5},{"name":"Marius","group":8},{"name":"BaronessT","group":5},{"name":"Mabeuf","group":8},{"name":"Enjolras","group":8},{"name":"Combeferre","group":8},{"name":"Prouvaire","group":8},{"name":"Feuilly","group":8},{"name":"Courfeyrac","group":8},{"name":"Bahorel","group":8},{"name":"Bossuet","group":8},{"name":"Joly","group":8},{"name":"Grantaire","group":8},{"name":"MotherPlutarch","group":9},{"name":"Gueulemer","group":4},{"name":"Babet","group":4},{"name":"Claquesous","group":4},{"name":"Montparnasse","group":4},{"name":"Toussaint","group":5},{"name":"Child1","group":10},{"name":"Child2","group":10},{"name":"Brujon","group":4},{"name":"Mme.Hucheloup","group":8}],"links":[{"source":1,"target":0,"value":1},{"source":2,"target":0,"value":8},{"source":3,"target":0,"value":10},{"source":3,"target":2,"value":6},{"source":4,"target":0,"value":1},{"source":5,"target":0,"value":1},{"source":6,"target":0,"value":1},{"source":7,"target":0,"value":1},{"source":8,"target":0,"value":2},{"source":9,"target":0,"value":1},{"source":11,"target":10,"value":1},{"source":11,"target":3,"value":3},{"source":11,"target":2,"value":3},{"source":11,"target":0,"value":5},{"source":12,"target":11,"value":1},{"source":13,"target":11,"value":1},{"source":14,"target":11,"value":1},{"source":15,"target":11,"value":1},{"source":17,"target":16,"value":4},{"source":18,"target":16,"value":4},{"source":18,"target":17,"value":4},{"source":19,"target":16,"value":4},{"source":19,"target":17,"value":4},{"source":19,"target":18,"value":4},{"source":20,"target":16,"value":3},{"source":20,"target":17,"value":3},{"source":20,"target":18,"value":3},{"source":20,"target":19,"value":4},{"source":21,"target":16,"value":3},{"source":21,"target":17,"value":3},{"source":21,"target":18,"value":3},{"source":21,"target":19,"value":3},{"source":21,"target":20,"value":5},{"source":22,"target":16,"value":3},{"source":22,"target":17,"value":3},{"source":22,"target":18,"value":3},{"source":22,"target":19,"value":3},{"source":22,"target":20,"value":4},{"source":22,"target":21,"value":4},{"source":23,"target":16,"value":3},{"source":23,"target":17,"value":3},{"source":23,"target":18,"value":3},{"source":23,"target":19,"value":3},{"source":23,"target":20,"value":4},{"source":23,"target":21,"value":4},{"source":23,"target":22,"value":4},{"source":23,"target":12,"value":2},{"source":23,"target":11,"value":9},{"source":24,"target":23,"value":2},{"source":24,"target":11,"value":7},{"source":25,"target":24,"value":13},{"source":25,"target":23,"value":1},{"source":25,"target":11,"value":12},{"source":26,"target":24,"value":4},{"source":26,"target":11,"value":31},{"source":26,"target":16,"value":1},{"source":26,"target":25,"value":1},{"source":27,"target":11,"value":17},{"source":27,"target":23,"value":5},{"source":27,"target":25,"value":5},{"source":27,"target":24,"value":1},{"source":27,"target":26,"value":1},{"source":28,"target":11,"value":8},{"source":28,"target":27,"value":1},{"source":29,"target":23,"value":1},{"source":29,"target":27,"value":1},{"source":29,"target":11,"value":2},{"source":30,"target":23,"value":1},{"source":31,"target":30,"value":2},{"source":31,"target":11,"value":3},{"source":31,"target":23,"value":2},{"source":31,"target":27,"value":1},{"source":32,"target":11,"value":1},{"source":33,"target":11,"value":2},{"source":33,"target":27,"value":1},{"source":34,"target":11,"value":3},{"source":34,"target":29,"value":2},{"source":35,"target":11,"value":3},{"source":35,"target":34,"value":3},{"source":35,"target":29,"value":2},{"source":36,"target":34,"value":2},{"source":36,"target":35,"value":2},{"source":36,"target":11,"value":2},{"source":36,"target":29,"value":1},{"source":37,"target":34,"value":2},{"source":37,"target":35,"value":2},{"source":37,"target":36,"value":2},{"source":37,"target":11,"value":2},{"source":37,"target":29,"value":1},{"source":38,"target":34,"value":2},{"source":38,"target":35,"value":2},{"source":38,"target":36,"value":2},{"source":38,"target":37,"value":2},{"source":38,"target":11,"value":2},{"source":38,"target":29,"value":1},{"source":39,"target":25,"value":1},{"source":40,"target":25,"value":1},{"source":41,"target":24,"value":2},{"source":41,"target":25,"value":3},{"source":42,"target":41,"value":2},{"source":42,"target":25,"value":2},{"source":42,"target":24,"value":1},{"source":43,"target":11,"value":3},{"source":43,"target":26,"value":1},{"source":43,"target":27,"value":1},{"source":44,"target":28,"value":3},{"source":44,"target":11,"value":1},{"source":45,"target":28,"value":2},{"source":47,"target":46,"value":1},{"source":48,"target":47,"value":2},{"source":48,"target":25,"value":1},{"source":48,"target":27,"value":1},{"source":48,"target":11,"value":1},{"source":49,"target":26,"value":3},{"source":49,"target":11,"value":2},{"source":50,"target":49,"value":1},{"source":50,"target":24,"value":1},{"source":51,"target":49,"value":9},{"source":51,"target":26,"value":2},{"source":51,"target":11,"value":2},{"source":52,"target":51,"value":1},{"source":52,"target":39,"value":1},{"source":53,"target":51,"value":1},{"source":54,"target":51,"value":2},{"source":54,"target":49,"value":1},{"source":54,"target":26,"value":1},{"source":55,"target":51,"value":6},{"source":55,"target":49,"value":12},{"source":55,"target":39,"value":1},{"source":55,"target":54,"value":1},{"source":55,"target":26,"value":21},{"source":55,"target":11,"value":19},{"source":55,"target":16,"value":1},{"source":55,"target":25,"value":2},{"source":55,"target":41,"value":5},{"source":55,"target":48,"value":4},{"source":56,"target":49,"value":1},{"source":56,"target":55,"value":1},{"source":57,"target":55,"value":1},{"source":57,"target":41,"value":1},{"source":57,"target":48,"value":1},{"source":58,"target":55,"value":7},{"source":58,"target":48,"value":7},{"source":58,"target":27,"value":6},{"source":58,"target":57,"value":1},{"source":58,"target":11,"value":4},{"source":59,"target":58,"value":15},{"source":59,"target":55,"value":5},{"source":59,"target":48,"value":6},{"source":59,"target":57,"value":2},{"source":60,"target":48,"value":1},{"source":60,"target":58,"value":4},{"source":60,"target":59,"value":2},{"source":61,"target":48,"value":2},{"source":61,"target":58,"value":6},{"source":61,"target":60,"value":2},{"source":61,"target":59,"value":5},{"source":61,"target":57,"value":1},{"source":61,"target":55,"value":1},{"source":62,"target":55,"value":9},{"source":62,"target":58,"value":17},{"source":62,"target":59,"value":13},{"source":62,"target":48,"value":7},{"source":62,"target":57,"value":2},{"source":62,"target":41,"value":1},{"source":62,"target":61,"value":6},{"source":62,"target":60,"value":3},{"source":63,"target":59,"value":5},{"source":63,"target":48,"value":5},{"source":63,"target":62,"value":6},{"source":63,"target":57,"value":2},{"source":63,"target":58,"value":4},{"source":63,"target":61,"value":3},{"source":63,"target":60,"value":2},{"source":63,"target":55,"value":1},{"source":64,"target":55,"value":5},{"source":64,"target":62,"value":12},{"source":64,"target":48,"value":5},{"source":64,"target":63,"value":4},{"source":64,"target":58,"value":10},{"source":64,"target":61,"value":6},{"source":64,"target":60,"value":2},{"source":64,"target":59,"value":9},{"source":64,"target":57,"value":1},{"source":64,"target":11,"value":1},{"source":65,"target":63,"value":5},{"source":65,"target":64,"value":7},{"source":65,"target":48,"value":3},{"source":65,"target":62,"value":5},{"source":65,"target":58,"value":5},{"source":65,"target":61,"value":5},{"source":65,"target":60,"value":2},{"source":65,"target":59,"value":5},{"source":65,"target":57,"value":1},{"source":65,"target":55,"value":2},{"source":66,"target":64,"value":3},{"source":66,"target":58,"value":3},{"source":66,"target":59,"value":1},{"source":66,"target":62,"value":2},{"source":66,"target":65,"value":2},{"source":66,"target":48,"value":1},{"source":66,"target":63,"value":1},{"source":66,"target":61,"value":1},{"source":66,"target":60,"value":1},{"source":67,"target":57,"value":3},{"source":68,"target":25,"value":5},{"source":68,"target":11,"value":1},{"source":68,"target":24,"value":1},{"source":68,"target":27,"value":1},{"source":68,"target":48,"value":1},{"source":68,"target":41,"value":1},{"source":69,"target":25,"value":6},{"source":69,"target":68,"value":6},{"source":69,"target":11,"value":1},{"source":69,"target":24,"value":1},{"source":69,"target":27,"value":2},{"source":69,"target":48,"value":1},{"source":69,"target":41,"value":1},{"source":70,"target":25,"value":4},{"source":70,"target":69,"value":4},{"source":70,"target":68,"value":4},{"source":70,"target":11,"value":1},{"source":70,"target":24,"value":1},{"source":70,"target":27,"value":1},{"source":70,"target":41,"value":1},{"source":70,"target":58,"value":1},{"source":71,"target":27,"value":1},{"source":71,"target":69,"value":2},{"source":71,"target":68,"value":2},{"source":71,"target":70,"value":2},{"source":71,"target":11,"value":1},{"source":71,"target":48,"value":1},{"source":71,"target":41,"value":1},{"source":71,"target":25,"value":1},{"source":72,"target":26,"value":2},{"source":72,"target":27,"value":1},{"source":72,"target":11,"value":1},{"source":73,"target":48,"value":2},{"source":74,"target":48,"value":2},{"source":74,"target":73,"value":3},{"source":75,"target":69,"value":3},{"source":75,"target":68,"value":3},{"source":75,"target":25,"value":3},{"source":75,"target":48,"value":1},{"source":75,"target":41,"value":1},{"source":75,"target":70,"value":1},{"source":75,"target":71,"value":1},{"source":76,"target":64,"value":1},{"source":76,"target":65,"value":1},{"source":76,"target":66,"value":1},{"source":76,"target":63,"value":1},{"source":76,"target":62,"value":1},{"source":76,"target":48,"value":1},{"source":76,"target":58,"value":1}]}; 
 
  force
      .nodes(json.nodes)
      .links(json.links)
      .start();

  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(json.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link");

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(json.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .call(force.drag);

  node.append("image")
      .attr("xlink:href", "https://github.com/favicon.ico")
      .attr("x", -8)
      .attr("y", -8)
      .attr("width", 16)
      .attr("height", 16);

  node.append("text")
      .attr("dx", 12)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name });

  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
  });
  d3.select("#fname").on("input", function() {
 var inputValue = this.value;
 node.each(function (d) {
  var highLight = "black";
  if(d.name.toLowerCase() == inputValue.toLowerCase()) highLight = "red";
  d3.select(this).style("fill", highLight);
 });
  });
```

```css
input[type=text] {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 12px 20px;
        margin: 8px 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 2px solid red;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<p>Text fields with borders:</p>

    <form>
      <label for="fname">Some Input</label>
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
    </form>
```